# Point domain to Route 53

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-route53, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, domain-name

I'm having issues to point a domain to a new server.

Currently our application is hosted in Google Clould.

We have a domain that is pointed to the public IP address of the Google Cloud instance and there is no other Google Cloud name servers attached to it. In our domain manager, we only have something like this:

```
domain.com     A       <google-cloud-ip-address>
```

We're moving this app to an AWS Beanstalk environment and these are the steps we did:

- Setup the app in an AWS Beanstalk Environment
- Create a Hosted Zone in Route 53
- Add an `A` Record Set with an Alias pointing to the Beanstalk application

This is what we have in Route 53 now:

```
domain.com     A       ALIAS application-domain.beanstalk.com
domain.com     NS      nameserver1.aws.com, nameserverN.aws.com ...
domain.com     SOA     ...
```

Route 53 only gives me name servers, but the domain is currently pointed to an IP address, how should I proceed in this case to point the domain to Route 53, since I don't have any public IP addresses to replace it on my domain manager?

What I tried to do is: remove the current IP record from the domain manager and add all the AWS name servers but that didn't work.

Anyone had this experience and could share something with me?

Thanks.

Comment: Where is the domain registered? Have you told the registrar to change the nameservers to the ones that Route53 gave you?

Comment: The domain is registered in Rebel.com but it's parked with them and we have a lot of different records for email, subdomains that point to other servers and we can't transfer to AWS now because of the downtime. That's the reason we'd like to point to an IP with an `A` record instead

Comment: If you want to use Route53, you have to tell Rebel.com to point the nameservers to the Route53 nameservers that you received. You don't have to transfer the domain though just the nameservers. If you want to keep the nameservers at Rebel.com you could also just add the A record there and point it to whatever IP amazon gave you.

Comment: Right, but how can I get an IP from Route 53? It just gives me nameservers

Comment: You don't want an IP from Route53, rather you need the IP for whatever service is actually hosting the site. In your case Beanstalk should give you an IP to use.

Comment: Alright I got the IP address from the beanstalk URL and pointed in my domain manager and it worked! Now the concern is, the IP address to the beanstalk environment changes automatically at some point?

Comment: The IP address changing is definitely a problem. Ideally Amazon would guarantee that you have a static IP address for your beanstalk environment. If not, you should look into using a CNAME record instead of an A record. With a CNAME you put the beanstalk domain instead of its IP into your DNS record, so if the IP address changes it won't matter.

Comment: Yeah that's what I'm worried about. Do you know I what occasion the IP address will change?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have any experience with Beanstalk. I would just look into using a CNAME record if possible.